# Android Wear - Action Drawer Icon Color

Tags: wear-os, action-drawer

I am using an action drawer with a menu. The icons appear in black as in the following screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to change the color of these icons, pretty much the same as in the design guidelines:

[image: Check guidelines: https://www.google.com/design/spec-wear/components/action-drawer.html#action-drawer-usage]

However, I cannot find where to do that or which style attribute will allow me to do so.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. Have you tried changing the whole icon instead?

Comment: I even changed the color of the icon itself in the xml (it's a vector drawable). Nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [CircledImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/CircledImageView.html) you can set the tint of the icon directly on the view using `setImageTint(int tint)`.

If you're using a traditional ImageView you need to create a Drawable from your icon resource and apply the tint to it, and then set it to the view:

```
Drawable iconDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon, mContext.getTheme());
iconDrawable.setTint(mContext.getColor(R.color.bg_color, mContext.getTheme()));
iconView.setImageDrawable(iconDrawable);
```

**EDIT:** To access icons in a menu you can do something like this when it's created:

```
for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
    Drawable iconDrawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
    iconDrawable.setTint(mContext.getColor(R.color.bg_color, mContext.getTheme()));
}
```

Comment: This is a menu, not a custom view. It's loaded from a menu xml.

Comment: Updated my answer. If this still doesn't help please post some code that shows what your menu XML looks like and how you're creating it in code.

Answer (score 0):

They changed the layout for the Action Drawer items without giving an option to change the color/disable it.

**v23/action_drawer_item_view.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wearable_support_action_drawer_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/action_drawer_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_drawer_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/action_item_icon_background"
        **android:tint="?android:attr/colorBackground"**
        android:padding="@dimen/action_drawer_item_icon_padding"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Since there's no access to the adapter, it's not possible change the color.